# How can I write stream data to an Excel file using ExcelJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

I want to write stream data the Excel file using this code but it just creates an empty file. Am I missing anything here?

```
const excel = require("exceljs");

async function processUpload(stream, filename) {
  let counter = 0;
  const options = {
    filename,
    useStyles: true,
    useSharedStrings: true,
  };

  const workbook = new excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter(options);
  const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("Sheet1");

  stream.on("data", (row) => {
    counter++;
    worksheet.addRow(row);
  });

  stream.on("end", () => {
    workbook.commit().then(() => {
      console.log("Workbook committed and uploaded to GCS.", counter);

      return filename;
    });
  });

  stream.on("error", (err) => console.error(err));
}
```

Comment: You want to write data in an existing excel file? Or upload it somewhere? I'm sorry but your question is not properly phrased

Comment: Hi @aekant, My use case is to upload this data stream to GCS in excel format. But for now I'm just trying to write this data new file. Once this will work I will just change the output stream at the place of filename. Let me know if need any more information

Comment: Thanks. As you said you want to write this data to a new file. In the question you have mentioned that this code writes the data to a new file. What is wrong here? Is the newly created file corrupted/empty or doesn't open or what?

Comment: above code just creates an empty file and the execution gets finished without writing any data
I had maintained counter just to verify whether we are receiving events or not but there is no issue in stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ran your code and figured that you need to specify the columns. Let say the data your are receiving is json objects with following keys

```
{
  name: 'John',
  age: 23,
  department: 'sales'
}
```

Then you can do the following

```
worksheet.columns = [
  { key: 'name', header: 'Name', width: 6 },
  { key: 'age', header: 'Age', width: 6 },
  { key: 'department', header: 'Department', width: 6 }
]
```

Where key should be the json field name. And header will be the column header in excel sheet and you can choose it to be whatever you want